# How to insert a string of size more than 4000 bytes into table column of type CLOB using SqL ldr

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I am trying to load a string of length more than 4000 into table of column type CLOB. I know we can do this using ananymous block. But how can I use this block in control file?

Comment: what you mean by sayin control file

Comment: While loading data using sqlldr to load the data into table from file. For that we use control file which have insertion logic like the data-seperator, the table into which we are loading the data. So I thought we can use the ananymous block there, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the max size of the `clob` as following:

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE <your_filename>
INTO TABLE <your_table_name>
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '<your_separator>'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
id,
<your_clob_column>    CHAR (6000), -- max value of your clob col, default is 255
other_fields
)
```

see the default is 255 so it will throw an error if you do not specify the size and load the data with length > 255 so It is better to always use size as mentioned above.

Cheers!!